# Load new page in RadWindow and then close the window from loaded form

Tags: javascript, telerik

I have a page1.aspx page which opens a RadWindow via javascript, inside the radwindow I am loading a page2.aspx with the following code

Page1 Code:

```
function test() {
  var wnd = window.radopen("page2.aspx", null);
  wnd.setSize(500, 400);
}
```

How can i close the radwindow from page2.aspx by clicking a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get a reference to it and call its close() method. See these articles:
http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-programming-opening-from-within-dialog.html and
http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-programming-radwindow-methods.html

In code:
function GetRadWindow()
{
    var oWindow = null; if (window.radWindow)
        oWindow = window.radWindow; else if (window.frameElement.radWindow)
        oWindow = window.frameElement.radWindow; return oWindow;
}

function closeMe()
{
    GetRadWindow().close();
    return false;
}